# Filter lines based on specific event and create a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a log file which contains timestamps and events

```
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol1  Sorting file  records (120 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol2  Sorting file  records (120 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:46 PST 2024 /vol/vol1  Sorting text records (120 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol2  Sorting file  records (120 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024  /vol/vol1 Sort (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol1  Pass (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024  /vol/vol2 Sort (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol2  Pass (0 entries)
   
    **Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol1 ( Filetering start )**
    Mon Jan 15 22:51:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol1  Sorting file  records (121 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:56:46 PST 2024 /vol/vol1 Sorting text records (122 entries)
   **Mon Jan 15 22:56:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol2 ( Filetering start )**
    Mon Jan 15 22:56:47 PST 2024  /vol/vol1 Sort (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:57:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol1 Pass (0 entries)
```

I am only interested in parsing lines and create dictionary of events with instance name and event that are after "Filetering start" event for each /vol/* instance.
Ex :

```
For /vol/vol1:
   Mon Jan 15 22:51:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol1  Sorting file  records (121 entries)
   Mon Jan 15 22:56:46 PST 2024 /vol/vol1 Sorting text records (122 entries)

For /vol/vol2:
   No lines as after filetering start there arent any events logged.
```

I tried to open file and create dictionary events by

```
 r = {
        'vol':[],
        'Sorting file':[],
    }
    with open(file) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if "Sorting file records" in line:
                line = line.split();
                r['Sorting File'].append(line[3])
                for i in line:
                    if "/vol/" in i:
                        r['vol'].append(i)
```

But the dictionary seems to take events before the filtering start as well , and I am not sure how we can delete all such entries. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to parse the text, e.g.:

```py
import re

log_text = """\
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol1  Sorting file  records (120 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol2  Sorting file  records (120 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:46 PST 2024 /vol/vol1  Sorting text records (120 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol2  Sorting file  records (120 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024  /vol/vol1 Sort (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol1  Pass (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024  /vol/vol2 Sort (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol2  Pass (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:16:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol1 ( Filtering start )
    Mon Jan 15 22:51:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol1  Sorting file  records (121 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:56:46 PST 2024 /vol/vol1 Sorting text records (122 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:56:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol2 ( Filtering start )
    Mon Jan 15 22:56:47 PST 2024  /vol/vol1 Sort (0 entries)
    Mon Jan 15 22:57:47 PST 2024 /vol/vol1 Pass (0 entries)"""

out = {}
for group in re.findall(
    r"\( Filtering start \)$(.*?)(?=[^\n]+\( Filtering start \)$)",
    log_text,
    flags=re.S | re.M,
):
    for line, vol, k in re.findall(
        r"([^\n]+(/vol/\S+)\s*(Sorting\s*\S+)[^\n]+)", group
    ):
        out.setdefault(vol, {}).setdefault(k, []).append(line.strip())

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "/vol/vol1": {
        "Sorting file": [
            "Mon Jan 15 22:51:46 PST 2024  /vol/vol1  Sorting file  records (121 entries)"
        ],
        "Sorting text": [
            "Mon Jan 15 22:56:46 PST 2024 /vol/vol1 Sorting text records (122 entries)"
        ],
    }
}
```